# Can i use my hosted WEB API (created in ASP.NET) in Mulesoft API manger?

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to learn mulesoft AnyPoint Platform, and trying to host an API using API Manager.

I already have an API created in asp.net, can i use it in API manager, or i need to create new API.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible if you are using Cloud based API Manager where below are the steps -

- Click on the "Add New API" button.
- Enter the API name of  Mythical
- Mobile Experience API (Replace Mythical with your preferred company
  name)
- Enter Version name of 1.0 Leave the the API Endpoint blank for
  now.
- Enter a description.

You should see the API administration page for your newly created API.  From this page, you can Define API in API designer using RAML, publish an API portal, and Configure endpoint for the API.

Note, If you are using on-prem API Gateway then you need to develop a proxy Mule application which then need to be deployed using auto discovery component so that it will register under api manager then You should see the API administration page for your newly created API.  From this page, you can Define API in API designer using RAML, publish an API portal, and Configure endpoint for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the API Manager for hosting the API.

Comment: Can i host my ASP.NET webAPI in API Manager, if yes then can you provide some reference material so i can start learning

Comment: You can do it as an normal API, that is to proxy all your request to api manager then route to your actual api

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the API created.